# Who first formulated the Political Business Cycle Theory?

Tags: business-cycles, austrian

The first time I saw it, was in Stephen Harper's Master's Thesis

http://dspace.ucalgary.ca/bitstream/1880/24345/1/1991_Harper.pdf

It comes across as being very similar to the Austrian Business Cycle Theory, but I have not come across it in their writings as of yet.

Who was the one to first coin and formulate the theory?

Answer (score 2):

Quick Wikipedia found :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_cycle

- Look at the section of Politically based business cycle

> The political business cycle theory is strongly linked to the name of
>   **Michał Kalecki** who discussed "the reluctance of the 'captains of
>   industry' to accept government intervention in the matter of
>   employment."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micha%C5%82_Kalecki

Answer (score 2):

The first scholar to model the intuition behind the political business cycle is William Nordhaus in a REStud article (1975).

Nordhaus (1975) is thus widely believed to be the seminal article in the literature: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2296528?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents